# How to set default value of array to empty with @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I'm having a controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff, method = GET)
public StuffDTO getStuff(
        @RequestParam(value = "stuffIds") List<Integer> ids) {
```

I know I can provide a default value like this:

```
@RequestParam(value = "1,2,3")
```

But how do I set default value to an empty list, not to deal with `null` lists inside the endpoint implementation?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just provide an empty string as a default value, no need for anything like `[]` etc.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff, method = GET)
public StuffDTO getStuff(
        @RequestParam(value = "stuffIds", defaultValue = "") List<Integer> ids) {
```